# Angular2 routeLink not working when querystring value is a 1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routelink

I have this router link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['RepairReturnListing', {country: someVal}]">Test</a>
```

In my component I define someVal like this:

```
export class RepairReturnCountByCountry {
   ...
   someVal: number = 1;
   ...
}
```

When the value is 1 I get this URL:

```
http://localhost:54675/repairReturnListing?country
```

Notice, no equals sign and no value.
I display the value in a div and it works as expected.

```
<div>{{someVal}}</div>
```

If I change it to anything other than one (even -1) I get a valid URL:

```
http://localhost:54675/repairReturnListing?country=0
http://localhost:54675/repairReturnListing?country=2
http://localhost:54675/repairReturnListing?country=777
http://localhost:54675/repairReturnListing?country=-1
```

If I remove someVal from the component I get:

```
http://localhost:54675/repairReturnListing?country=null
```

I change someVal to a string but I get the same results:

```
 someVal: string = '1';
```

Here is my routeConfig:

```
 @RouteConfig([
        { path: '/repairReturnListing', name: 'RepairReturnListing', component: ListingComponent, useAsDefault: false }
])
```

Comment: There [was an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5346) when using the number 1 as parameter but it was fixed, what angular2 version are you using?

Comment: I'm was using 2.0.0-beta.0.  I upgraded to 2.0.0-beta.9 but now I can't build.  I'l going through the error messages now.  When was it fixed?  It looks like .9 from that link but I'm not sure.

Comment: The errors may be another question, I can confirm that the problem exists in beta.0, I upgraded to beta.9 and it works correctly Check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5RU8DzpZynxogWkfOiWe?p=preview) (I took it from the issue I referenced).

Comment: After upgrading I get erorrs like:
angular2/src/router/directives/router_link"' has no exported member 'RouterLink' is router.d.ts
and
Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.  in collection.d.ts

Comment: that's another question. Make another or google them. After you solved those errors see if this error persists, if it doesn't you can come over here and answer yourself. It seems like you have wrong paths over there (you shouldn't import RouterLink from there but from `angular2/router`).